# c#.net overwrite prompt not working

Tags: c#, savefiledialog

I have a user data report that needs to be saved as pdf, but when I put the overwrite prompt to true the overwrite message when there is a filename that exist is not showing. Here's my code.

```
SaveFileDialog svg = new SaveFileDialog();
svg.FileName = "Data Report - All Books";//set default file name
svg.Filter = "Pdf Files|*.pdf";

if (svg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    svg.OverwritePrompt = true;//tell user to overwrite existing file name
    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(svg.FileName + ".pdf", FileMode.Create))
    {
        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A1, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, stream);

        pdfDoc.Open();
        pdfDoc.Add(pdfTable);
        pdfDoc.Close();
        stream.Close();
    }
    MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Successfully save PDF report.", "SUCESS!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the overwrite prompt before dialog is shown. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.overwriteprompt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does mention OverWritePrompt by default is set to true.

```
SaveFileDialog svg = new SaveFileDialog();
svg.FileName = "Data Report - All Books";//set default file name
svg.Filter = "Pdf Files|*.pdf";

//This needs to be before dialog is shown.
svg.OverwritePrompt = true;//tell user to overwrite
if (svg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(svg.FileName + ".pdf", FileMode.Create))
    {
        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A1, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, stream);

        pdfDoc.Open();
        pdfDoc.Add(pdfTable);
        pdfDoc.Close();
        stream.Close();
    }
    MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Successfully save PDF report.", "SUCESS!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```

Comment: Already did that but no good, there is still no overwrite message appear. But the CreatePrompt and CheckFileExist are working.

Comment: @saga perhaps, it is the extension